# JAXB Change Default Naming Convertor

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

With the help of JAXB, I want to do some marshaling and unmarshaling by reusing some existing XML/classes with no JAXB type/element annotations.

Is it possible to change default JAXB naming mapping configuration to map all tags/fields like that "firstName->FirstName" without introducing any annotations?

I mean these class fields (note: they start with small letter)

```
class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName; 
}
```

to map to that XML (note: they start with the capital letter):

```
<Person>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
</Person>
```

Comment: I don't think that the JAXB implementation in the JDK can do this. If you use an alternative implementation such as EclipseLink MOXy, this might be possible. See: [Customizing XML Name Conversions](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/moxy/advanced_concepts002.htm#CHDCCCAF)

Comment: Thanks, @Jesper. I saw this annotation `XMLNameTransformer` may do the job but do not want to introduce new library dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to Jesper's suggestion to use MOXy is to filter the input and output xml using `StreamReaderDelegate` and `DelegatingXMLStreamWriter`.

For unmarshalling you can do:

```
String xml = "<Person><FirstName>John</FirstName><LastName>Doe</LastName></Person>";

XMLStreamReader xsr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(xml));
xsr = new StreamReaderDelegate(xsr) {
    @Override
    public String getLocalName() {
        String s = super.getLocalName(); 
        return Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1); 
    }
};

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Person person = u.unmarshal(xsr, Person.class).getValue();
```

And simillary for marshling:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XMLStreamWriter xsw = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamWriter(sw);
xsw = new DelegatingXMLStreamWriter(xsw) {
    @Override
    public void writeStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String namespaceURI) throws XMLStreamException {
        String s = localName;
        super.writeStartElement(prefix, Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1), namespaceURI);
    }
};

Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
JAXBElement<Person> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<Person>(new QName(Person.class.getSimpleName()), Person.class, person);
m.marshal(jaxbElement, xsw);
```

`DelegatingXMLStreamWriter` is for some reason package private but it's a simple class and you can just copy the source from [here](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.5.1/com/sun/xml/txw2/output/DelegatingXMLStreamWriter.java).

This solution is based on [this blog post](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/case-insensitive-unmarshalling.html).

Comment: Thanks, @Oleg. Works like a charm. I thought some sort of xml preprocessing/transformation might do the job but that is much better solution.